# app.MapFallbackToFile causes reload the entire SPA site if the URL typed manually

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api, vuejs3, vue-router, single-page-application

I use the latest [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022) SPA + .Net Core-based Web APi pattern where the FE referenced to BE, FE serves proxy to BE during development, and `app.UseDefaultFiles()`serves `index.html` where the SPA resides during production. This pattern means no proxy middleware is required as it was in opposite direction when the BE serves FE as a proxy.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles(); <-- Here the site is loaded first time
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html"); <-- Here the site is reloaded if URL typed(changed) manually
```

Client-side routing is the point. Specifically, I use Vue Router and IIS hosting. When the site is already opened, and a user types URL in the browser, it falls down to `app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html")` and then Vue router handles the route.

The problem is that the site is always completely reloading when the URL is just changed (let say from mysite.com/a to mysite.com/b) in this scenario, as I would press F5. It's not always necessarily bad but I would like to control it.

The question is: how to get rid of `app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html")` and somehow pass the captured URL to the SPA, as it would be naked SPA without backend which now stays in front of frontend.

Answer (score 1):

If have tried Vue Spa with ASP.NET Core 6 minimal setup and it seems for me, that there is no way to achieve what you want.

When user enters or changes the URL address, the browser navigate away from the page and do a `GET` request to `BE` (Backend).
Here is the `catch-all fallback route` required, otherwise the user gets the 404 error from the web server.

I presume you use the `HTML5 History Mode`. Here is a part from the [Vue Router Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode) about this problem.

> Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper
> server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access
> https://example.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's
> ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
> catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
> static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app
> lives in. Beautiful, again!

If somebody yet knows the solution, please post a new answer.
It would be great to know how to do it!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that I'm not alone!)